# Evaporation as a Feedback

Tags: energy

I've never thought of the process of heating water in a kettle as involving feedback (except in the sense of changes to the element resistance with water temperature or the action of the cut-off switch on boiling).  However, I have been called ignorant for my lack of understanding:

```
Raff, you are showing your ignorance of both feedbacks and climate.

Putting water into a kettle IS a feedback. If the water wasn't 
there the kettle would be a damn sight hotter.
The heat of the kettle causes the water to be hotter, causing 
steam, which escapes and loses the system energy. the water 
doesn't do that on its own, it does it because of the kettle 
getting hotter and heating the water. And its behaviour when 
that happens affects the temperature of the kettle (cools it).
```

This is from http://www.bishop-hill.net/discussion/post/2436923?currentPage=3

I can see that if there was no water in the kettle it would get much hotter until the safety cut-out caused it to turn off.  This would be an example of feedback.  And clearly as the kettle heats up there will be some evaporation (and radiation and conduction of heat) which will means the water heats up slower than it otherwise would. But that is just an energy loss from the system. I don't see it feeding back and modifying the system in any way.

Can the process of heating the kettle be considered to involve feedback in the way suggested?

Comment: The feedback in global warming in certainly more specific than this. In that case, evaporating more water causes the system to absorb more heat. Nothing matching this dynamic is present with the kettle. The stove's range does have temperature sensitivity, but resistance tends to increase with higher temperature, making the water's effect a negative feedback as opposed to a positive one with regard to global warming water vapor. This effect is minimal anyway.

Comment: As you heat up the empty kettle to a higher temperature, it will radiate away more energy (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law). Would you consider that "feedback?" I would consider it "cause and effect."

Comment: This stabilizing negative feedback effect is the principle of Le Chatelier, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Chatelier%27s_principle . Negative feedback is not necessarily stabilizing as simple linear systems with 3rd order denominator (3 integrators) will show but near stable equilibrium and maximum entropy Le Chatelier's principle holds.

Answer (score 0):

In my definition of "feedback", the magnitude of the effect of an action somehow affects the evolution of the system state over time. There is negative feedback (the system ends up resisting the change) and positive feedback (a shift away from equilibrium causes a runaway situation).

In the case of boiling water - as the water heats up, it will lose heat more quickly because of evaporation (typically minimized in a little by putting a lid on it). This means that raising the temperature of water that's already hot is harder - and that can be considered negative feedback for the water-heating process.

Putting a lid on the kettle would make the effect less strong - taking the kid off and blowing a fan across the surface of the water would make it stronger.

But I would hesitate to call anyone "ignorant" because they see things differently.